# smbclient error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: samba

steps to reproduce:

1. (host) sudo ufw disable
2. (host) sudo smbclient -L localhost
3. (client) sudo smbclient -L myhost.ip:

```
do_connect: Connection to myhost.ip failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)-
```